# MenuItemImpl cannot be cast to RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, badge, android-toolbar

I want to display a (custom) `RelativeLayout` in my `Toolbar` but I get following runtime error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout
        at com.mobven.hesapal.activities.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:163)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2588)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:275)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:276)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:79)
        at android.support.v7.widget.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:49)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:459)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:69)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I want to implement something like a shopping cart (that includes how many items are in above a cart icon).

*toolbar_cart_badge.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

*menu_main.xml*

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/layout_item"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.RelativeLayout"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:title="Text 1"/>

</menu>
```

Here is my failing code:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.layout_item);
        View inflated = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tollbar_cart_badge, null);
        rl.addView(inflated);
        return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You are doing is absolutely incorrect. `menu.findItem(id)` returns `MenuItem`, thus it can't be casted to `RelativeLayout`. Firstly, `MenuItem` is interface and RelativeLayout does not implements this interface.

You can add your custom layout in `Toolbar` with `toolbar.addView(inflatedView)`, if this is your intention of adding custom view to the `Toolbar`. Or reference it in the layout xml:

```
<Toolbar 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
   >
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2" />
</RelativeLayout>
</Toolbar>
```

This is reasonable and will work as you would add custom view to old `ActionBar`

If you intention is to add view to `MenuItem` you can do it with `MenuItemCompat.setActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.layout_item),R.layout.tollbar_cart_badge);`

Comment: Thank you for solution @Nikola, but there is no click effect on action item when clicked the view, normally there should be click effect when option items clicked how can i implement the same effect ?